# ComboBox values are displaying behind the window in gwtext

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

I added a ComboBox to a FlexTable  and added that flextable to a Window of gwtext.But Now while clicking the ComboBox,the values in the ComboBox are displaying behind the Window.

I created Window and added the ContentPanel which contains the FlexTable as below:

```
                window = new com.gwtext.client.widgets.Window();
                window.setAutoWidth(true);
                window.setWidth("1200");
                window.setHeight("350");
                window.setTitle("RRF New Joinee List");
                window.setClosable(true);
                window.setModal(true);
                window.setPlain(true);
                window.setCloseAction(com.gwtext.client.widgets.Window.HIDE);
                window.add(cpfilter);

                window.add(panelForPopUpNew);
                window.show();
```

Please give suggestion how to resolve this.

Comment: You can try to set z-index CSS property of combo box higher than window

Comment: I already tried setZIndex.But Getting exception,use this method before rendering.

Comment: As error you should setZIndex() before render. You can set z-index on window's beforeShow event.

Comment: hi @Gundamaiah did you find a solution for this?